# mysqli won't insert when date is null

Tags: php, mysqli

in my table, there's a column named receivedOn which is a date type. so if I did this

```
$receivedOn= "2013-11-11";
$stmt = $dbi->prepare("insert into mytable(somedata,receivedOn) values (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$somedata,$receivedOn); 
$result = $stmt->execute() or die (mysqli_error($dbi)");
```

it will insert the data successfully, but if $receivedOn is empty, it will not insert the data and would seem like it just hang there. no errors were returned. how can I make mysqli to insert the data, even if when receivedOn is empty? I can insert data with emtpy receivedOn using normal mysql query (non-mysqli)

Comment: You have to ALTER the column to receive nulls

Comment: yes the column can already receive nulls.. that's why I have no problem inserting null receivedOn value using normal mysql query.. buy not mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing:

```
$receivedOn = ($receivedOn != '') ? $receivedOn : NULL;
$stmt = $dbi->prepare("insert into mytable(somedata,receivedOn) values (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$somedata,$receivedOn); 
...
```